# Learn Rails tutorial - Deployment to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have been following the Learn Rails tutorial by Daniel Kehoe, and everything was working fine in development.

When moving to Heroku, I had to deal with a thread_safe version problem (updating to v0.3.3) but ended up with:

```
Launching... done, v7
```

However, when I visit the app website — http://learnrailstutorial.herokuapp.com — I get the following error message:

> Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the
>   application owner, check your logs for details.

Here is what I get in the logs:

```
$ heroku logs
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897931+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897933+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897934+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897935+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897940+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897942+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897946+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897948+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897949+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897950+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897955+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897956+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897953+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897958+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897960+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897963+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897965+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897966+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897969+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897967+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897970+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.897971+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-04-13T18:35:12.916586+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:57365
2014-04-13T18:35:12.916579+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin
2014-04-13T18:35:12.916588+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-04-13T18:35:12.916592+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-04-13T18:35:12.916590+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-04-13T18:35:14.054222+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-13T18:35:14.055058+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-04-13T18:35:14.042388+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-13T18:35:18.252062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 40719 -e production`
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022699+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environments/production.rb:82:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022703+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022693+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing': undefined method `learnrailstutorial' for #<LearnRails::Application:0x007fea7aac87f0> (NoMethodError)
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022701+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022704+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022705+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022707+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022709+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022712+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022715+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022716+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022724+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022711+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022726+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022725+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022713+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022717+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022729+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022730+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022731+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022722+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022735+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022732+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022739+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022740+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022737+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022741+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022743+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022744+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022754+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022753+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022747+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022749+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022750+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022751+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022756+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022758+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022759+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022760+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022755+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022763+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022764+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022769+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022765+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022768+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022771+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.022772+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-04-13T18:35:21.042421+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin
2014-04-13T18:35:21.042428+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:40719
2014-04-13T18:35:21.042430+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-04-13T18:35:21.042432+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-04-13T18:35:21.042433+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-04-13T18:35:22.361455+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-13T18:35:22.374267+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-13T18:36:06.763404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=learnrailstutorial.herokuapp.com request_id=5c27afbd-ac1c-4525-b7eb-0cea294ec22b fwd="76.88.15.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-04-13T18:36:18.195687+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=learnrailstutorial.herokuapp.com request_id=9431bd21-bb32-4826-b5ea-10e578db1b22 fwd="76.88.15.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-04-13T18:37:19.982092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=learnrailstutorial.herokuapp.com request_id=e7dcd7ad-3120-4157-b93e-63e89f589aeb fwd="76.88.15.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-04-13T18:39:17.034025+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=learnrailstutorial.herokuapp.com request_id=2f0adb38-6273-42e9-90a4-43f92fc6f7bd fwd="76.88.15.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Any idea of a way to troubleshoot this?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: here is my production.rb file

```
LearnRails::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # email enabled in production
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => learnrailstutorial.herokuapp.com }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: learnrailstutorial.herokuapp.com,
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
    }
end
```

and here are my routes:

```
LearnRails::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :visitors, only: [:new, :create]
  root to: 'visitors#new'
end
```

Comment: Can you share your `production.rb` file.

Comment: Do you have a root route defined in routes.rb?

Comment: @KirtiThorat: Yes, I just put added it to the question.

Comment: @kitsched: I just added my routes.rb file to the question, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `production.rb`,

Change

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => learnrailstutorial.herokuapp.com }
```

To

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "learnrailstutorial.herokuapp.com" }
```

Similarly update the `domain` option value in `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings`.

As the hostname is not in *quotes*, Rails interprets it as a method name and goes looking for its definition. If you notice the error logs, you would see

`method_missing': undefined method 'learnrailstutorial`

Comment: This change actually solved the problem.
But I also had to change place the second occurrence of the domaine name into quotes, in the very same production.rb file.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help. :) Please accept the answer when you get a chance.